# Remote Maintenance Plans in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, maintenance-plan

I've set up a maintenance plan in instance #1 of SQL Server 2008.  In theory, it will connect to instance #2 and back up those databases to the hard drive of instance #1.

I have:

- Created a login on instance #2
- Given that login the correct permissions needed to back-up a database (I tested it)
- Created a working connection in the maintenance plan to instance #2 (I tested it)

However, the plan will not execute and the only error that I get is "The maintenance plan failed."  Is there something that I'm missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:  I created a maintenance plan on instance #2 that would back up instance #2's databases and then ship them over to the machine that instance #1 is installed on.  This did not work either!

Comment: are you referencing the database as a network drive in the plan?  i've never heard of doing maintenance plans remotely.  What's the reasoning?  Consolidation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I added instance #2 as a connection on instance #1's maintenance plan.  Instance #1 is very slow and has a large amount of free space and instance #2 is very fast and has a small amount of free space.  We would like to keep our hot data on instance #2 and back up to instance #1.

Answer (score 0):

if it's sql server agent executing the maintenance plan check its permission  instance #2 or use a proxy account for SSIS exectuion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It looks like the permissions are correct.  I'd like to stay away from proxy accounts if possible.  Any other suggestions?